# spark streaming integration flume

Tags: flume, spark-streaming

I follow the guid of spark streaming + flume integration. But i can't get any events in the end.
(https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-flume-integration.html)
Can any one help me analysis it?
In the fume, I created the file of  "avro_flume.conf" as follows:

## Describe/configure the source

```
a1.sources = r1
a1.channels = c1
a1.sources.r1.type = avro
a1.sources.r1.channels = c1
a1.sources.r1.bind = 123.57.54.113
a1.sources.r1.port = 4141
```

## Describe the sink

```
a1.sinks = k1
a1.sinks.k1.type = avro
```

## Use a channel which buffers events in memory

```
a1.channels.c1.type = memory
a1.channels.c1.capacity = 1000
a1.channels.c1.transactionCapacity = 100
```

## Bind the source and sink to the channel

```
a1.sources.r1.channels = c1
a1.sinks.k1.channel = c1
a1.sinks.k1.hostname = 123.57.54.113
a1.sinks.k1.port = 6666
a1.sources = r1
a1.sinks = spark
a1.channels = c1
```

In the file ,  123.57.54.113 is the ip of localhost.

## I start the programing as follows:

## 1.Start agent

```
flume-ng agent -c . -f conf/avro_spark.conf -n a1 Start Spark-streaming
```

## 2.Start spark-streaming example

```
bin/run-example org.apache.spark.examples.streaming.FlumeEventCount 123.57.54.113 6666
```

## 3.Then I start the avro-cilent

```
flume-ng avro-client -c . -H 123.57.54.113 -p 4141 -F test/log.01
```

## 4.test/log.01"  is a file created by echo which contains some string

In the end ,there is no events at all.

What's the problem? 
Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

I see "a1.sinks = spark" under heading "Binding the source and sink to the channel". But the sink with name "spark" is not defined elsewhere in your configuration.
Are you trying approach 1 or approach 2 from "https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-flume-integration.html"?

Try removing the line "a1.sinks = spark" if you are trying approach 1.

For approach 2 use the following template:

```
agent.sinks = spark
agent.sinks.spark.type = org.apache.spark.streaming.flume.sink.SparkSink
agent.sinks.spark.hostname = <hostname of the local machine>
agent.sinks.spark.port = <port to listen on for connection from Spark>
agent.sinks.spark.channel = memoryChannel
```